# Xampp-installation problems; ports not free and Apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp

I tried installing xampp from the following site: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

I had problems installing. When the control panel runs, it shows green signal for MySql and Mercury only, and especially when I start Apache, it gives an Exception.

And at some point it says to disable UAC, but I guess that is not recommended in Windows, so what should I do?

And I also received an error which said "class not registered".

The following are the errors I receive when I start Apache:

```
11:27:40  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:27:40  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1476!
11:27:40  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:27:40  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:27:40  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a                 different port
11:27:40  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
12:04:47  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1476!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:04:47  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:04:47  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a             different port
12:04:47  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1476!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:04:47  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:04:47  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
12:04:47  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
12:04:52  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
12:04:53  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
12:04:53  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:04:53  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:04:53  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:04:53  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:04:53  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

Where are these logs buttons? And from where to free the ports?. I don't use Skype so my port 80 is probably free. Please help.

Comment: MySql and Mercury, I guess works fine as there is a green tick in front of them..Plz help sumone??

Comment: I edited your question, but you still need to clarify the final paragraph, which I could not help with (i.e. where you say "Where are these logs buttons? And from where to free the ports?").

Comment: See if you see last lines of error it says "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"   and for the ports  part its also in the error:

Comment: 11:27:40  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1476!
11:27:40  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:27:40  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:27:40  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a                 different port
11:27:40  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
12:04:47  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1476!
12:04:47  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured

Comment: +1 Good, the explanation you provided helps in the understanding of your question.

Comment: Well I finally got the answer and the installation is done..So this is  might be helpful for someone in need..:)..I disabled UAC control and restarted it den it works ... but contrary to my expectation after enabling UAC also its working fine..Hope this helps to sumone in need..

Comment: +1 You can (and should) answer your own question.  As an answer, it will be much more visible than a comment.  Please consider doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by disabling UAC control and restarted it. But then contrary to my expectation after enabling UAC again it is still working fine.