# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. Changed ports, Still not working

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP and for some reason when I start running Apache, it doesn't run. I'm not using Skype and also changed the port from 80 to 8080,7777. But nothing seems to work.
Also when I try opening the logs, they are empty.

The detailed error which I get is as follows

```
10:29:55 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
10:29:55 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:29:57 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Please someone help

Comment: It looks like it's a windows machine, which version?  You might try running it from the command line or with a debugger...

Comment: did you try what the error messag says? "Press the Logs button to view error logs"? We can't help you, since there's a near infinite number of ways for Apache to fail. We're not here to play "guess the problem".

Comment: As I told you, when i click on logs and select either access.log/ error.log/php_error_log , neither of them have anything within them. They all are empty.

Comment: @abiessu I'm running Win7 Sp1. Also while setting up XAMPP, I'd got some UAC warning, which I'd ignored. Although I don't remember what it was exactly. But could it lead to this issue?

Comment: You can't exactly ignore a UAC, you either say "yes, no" or "cancel".  I assume that Apache ran successfully prior to the XAMPP installation?  Are you running Apache as administrator (on a taskbar icon, SHIFT-right-click to see this option)?  Did you run the installation process as administrator?  Note that it does not matter if your user account has administrative privileges, you have to invoke "Run As Administrator" for certain actions in Win7...

Comment: Since you saw the UAC warning, consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888848/xampp-installation-problems-ports-not-free-and-apache-not-starting?rq=1) and its associated answer...

Comment: Well, I'd formatted my laptop so this was a fresh install. On my laptop, I only have one user account which is admin and as far as I remember, the installation had run using admin privileges

Answer (score 1):

Well,somehow resinstalling XAMPP worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install (or unzip) the xampp folder to the root directory (C:\). It helped me even when Skype was listening on the same port apache still would boot up.

Than it is good practise to change http port and ssl port to some different number up to 65535. You have to change it in 3 steps:

1) In Config Panel -> Service and Port Settings -> Main Port & SSL Port

2) Apache (httpd.conf)

3) Apache (httpd-ssl.conf)